# Update to Android 5.0 Lollipop on Nexus 7

Tags: updates, 5.0-lollipop, operating-system

I currently own a Nexus 7 (2013) device, but after updating the OS several times, I am stuck at Android 4.4.4. I know that Android 5.0 Lollipop has been released for the Nexus 7, but I don't know why I can't download it.

Is there a way for me to download it without sideloading/factory imaging my device?

Comment: You can sideload without wiping your data, if that's what you're worried about.

Comment: I'm not worried about wiping my data, I'm just worried about accidentally messing up my device. So if it comes down to either sideloading or waiting a couple weeks for an update, I'll just wait.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, you get updates to your device from google on the basis of the date on which you bought the device. That is if you bought a tab 5 months ago and one yesterday the one which was bought earlier will receive update first. So don't worry when you have upgrade chance you will be notified.

Did your tab notified you that you have a upgrade available?
If yes did you actually download the upgrade for 5.0?

Comment: Okay, thank you. I had just purchased it yesterday, and I was able to update to 4.4.4, but not any further than that. I have checked multiple times, and it says my device is up to date (at 4.4.4). Do you have any guess as to when it should receive the update?

Comment: In about 15 days or a month.

Comment: share your joy here when you get your lollipop...!! :)

Comment: Yes please do let us know, I bought my Nexus 7 2013 Wifi at release 18 months ago and its sitting at 4.4.4 with no update.

Comment: It still hasn't updated... Is it possible that I missed the rollout and its done?

Comment: You should have a look here. http://www.forbes.com/sites/ewanspence/2015/01/11/nobody-is-using-android-lollipop/

Comment: If you are ready to spend some time and manually upgrade to Lollipop, follow instructions given here. http://www.androidpolice.com/2014/12/23/flash-all-the-things-lollipop-ota-update-zip-file-roundup/